# Why am I getting invalid hooks error in the console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I cannot figure out for the life of me why I'm getting this error when using mutations via React Query.  Any sort of feedback would be appreciated.

**Note:**
I'm using inside a function (React) component so I'm not sure why this error's getting thrown.

error:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

code:

```
const addAsset = (asset) => {
    return axios.post('http://localhost/api/file-upload', asset);
}

const fileUpload = () => {
    const url = 'http://localhost/api/file-upload';

    let formData = new FormData();
    let imagefile = document.querySelector('#file');
    formData.append("image", imagefile.files[0]);

    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    }

    axios.post(url, formData, {headers})
        .then(resp => {
            let okStatus       = resp.status;
            let successMessage = resp.data.message;

            if(okStatus) {
                setShow(false);
            }

            setUploadSuccess(okStatus);
            setStatusMessage(successMessage);
            setStatusCode(okStatus);
        }).catch(error => {
        let errorMessage       = error.response.data.message;
        let errorStatus        = error.response.status;

        setStatusMessage(errorMessage);
        setStatusCode(errorStatus);
    });

    const queryClient = useQueryClient();

    return useMutation(addAsset, {
        onSuccess: () => {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries('uploads');
        }
    });
}

return(<Button variant="primary" onClick={fileUpload}>Upload!</Button>);
```

Comment: Which one of those three reasons do you believe is the issue?

Comment: @Bravo not sure, that's why I'm asking

Comment: Where are you calling `fileUpload`? It's apparently not being called during rendering of a function component.

Comment: @NicholasTower it's pointing to an `onClick` button attribute

Comment: You cannot call hooks in an onClick callback, just in the body of a function component. Can you move  `useQueryClient` and `useMutation` outside of fileUpload?

Comment: @NicholasTower I've tried that before, that doesn't work.  It gives an error about detecting a change in the order of Hooks called by the component

Comment: I ask, because you could easily rule out at least two of those (1 and 3) - how can you possibly not know if you're breaking rules 1 and 3 or not?

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, hooks can only be called in the body of a function component. They cannot be called in an onClick callback. You will need to move the hook calls out of fileUpload.

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient();

const { mutate } = useMutation(addAsset, {
  onSuccess: () => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries('uploads');
  }
});

const fileUpload = () => {
  const url = 'http://localhost/api/file-upload';
  // ...
  axios.post(url, formData, {headers})
     .then(
  // ...

  mutate(/* insert variables here */);
}
```

See also: [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)